# Python 3 keeps crashing

Tags: python, macos, crash, crash-reports, python-3.3

I'm new to python and can't figure out how to fix this problem. Idle was working fine until I accidentally used eval_input() in python 2 instead of python 3 and I think that might be how this problem start because after that, it kept crashing.

Here is the error report I get:

```
2013-07-11 14:35:40.354 Python[88770:f07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error (1000) creating window shape'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ce510a6 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8e6de3f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ce50e7c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b24aeb3 _NXCreateWindowWithStyleMask + 276
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b2df91f _NSCreateWindow + 64
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b15b4bd -[NSWindow _commonAwake] + 2159
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b20b85b -[NSWindow _makeKeyRegardlessOfVisibility] + 88
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b20b7c5 -[NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:] + 25
    8   Tk                                  0x00000001014425bf XMapWindow + 156
    9   Tk                                  0x00000001013ae826 Tk_MapWindow + 89
    10  Tk                                  0x00000001013b76f6 MapFrame + 62
    11  Tcl                                 0x0000000101308b87 TclServiceIdle + 76
    12  Tcl                                 0x00000001012ed112 Tcl_DoOneEvent + 329
    13  Tk                                  0x000000010138dba3 Tk_UpdateObjCmd + 162
    14  Tcl                                 0x0000000101287599 TclEvalObjvInternal + 782
    15  Tcl                                 0x0000000101288772 Tcl_EvalObjv + 66
    16  _tkinter.so                         0x000000010126c5be Tkapp_Call + 190
    17  Python                              0x00000001000df35e PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 29822
    18  Python                              0x00000001000deaff PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 27679
    19  Python                              0x00000001000deaff PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 27679
    20  Python                              0x00000001000deaff PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 27679
    21  Python                              0x00000001000e04e8 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2296
    22  Python                              0x000000010003e03a function_call + 186
    23  Python                              0x000000010000dcc8 PyObject_Call + 104
    24  Python                              0x00000001000da343 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9315
    25  Python                              0x00000001000e04e8 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2296
    26  Python                              0x000000010003e03a function_call + 186
    27  Python                              0x000000010000dcc8 PyObject_Call + 104
    28  Python                              0x00000001000da343 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9315
    29  Python                              0x00000001000e04e8 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2296
    30  Python                              0x000000010003e03a function_call + 186
    31  Python                              0x000000010000dcc8 PyObject_Call + 104
    32  Python                              0x00000001000284aa method_call + 138
    33  Python                              0x000000010000dcc8 PyObject_Call + 104
    34  Python                              0x00000001000d6497 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 87
    35  _tkinter.so                         0x000000010126a8a8 PythonCmd + 456
    36  Tcl                                 0x0000000101284399 TclInvokeStringCommand + 105
    37  Tcl                                 0x0000000101287599 TclEvalObjvInternal + 782
    38  Tcl                                 0x00000001012c0ce1 TclExecuteByteCode + 4376
    39  Tcl                                 0x00000001012c794e TclCompEvalObj + 456
    40  Tcl                                 0x0000000101288b3f TclEvalObjEx + 809
    41  Tcl                                 0x0000000101308e84 AfterProc + 86
    42  Tcl                                 0x0000000101308d81 TimerHandlerEventProc + 104
    43  Tcl                                 0x00000001012ece0f Tcl_ServiceEvent + 147
    44  Tcl                                 0x00000001012ed103 Tcl_DoOneEvent + 314
    45  _tkinter.so                         0x0000000101269e51 Tkapp_MainLoop + 177
    46  Python                              0x00000001000df35e PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 29822
    47  Python                              0x00000001000e04e8 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2296
    48  Python                              0x00000001000de977 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 27287
    49  Python                              0x00000001000deaff PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 27679
    50  Python                              0x00000001000e04e8 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2296
    51  Python                              0x00000001000e05af PyEval_EvalCode + 63
    52  Python                              0x000000010010748b PyRun_FileExFlags + 187
    53  Python                              0x000000010010781d PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 717
    54  Python                              0x000000010011e853 Py_Main + 3203
    55  Python                              0x0000000100000e1c Python + 3612
    56  Python                              0x0000000100000c74 Python + 3188
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
Abort trap: 6
```

any ideas? thanks!

Comment: also im on a mac, version 10.8.2

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue16177

Comment: could you just uninstall python3 and reinstall it? Doesn't take long to redo the install...

Comment: Robert, I've look at the url before and still no help :(. I've also tried uninstalling python 3 and reinstalling it and I'm still getting the problem.